# Pass variables and values to a function (wildcard?)

Tags: python

I'm writing an ArcGIS function and I want to pass the variable and value as parameters (if possible).

Here's my code:

```
from arcgis.gis import *
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer

URL = 'http://url_to_arcgis_server'
# QUERY =  HERE LIES THE PROBLEM

def get_features(url, query):
    features = []
    f = FeatureLayer(url = url)
    f_set = f.query(where = '1=1', out_sr = '4326')
    for f in f_set:
        features.append(f.as_dict)
    return features

get_features(URL, QUERY)
```

where query can be chosen from [this list](https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.query) of parameters.

Is there a way that I can pass `where = '1=1'` and `out_sr = '4326'` to `QUERY`? I tried encapsulating in quotes (`QUERY = "where = '1=1', out_sr = '4326'"`), but that does not work.

ArcGIS says that queries are based on SQL statements.

Comment: You can "do 'this' " 'or "that" ' and it should work, but here I guess that the format of your input that's not correct, can you show us the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QUERY = { 'where': '1=1', 'out_sr': '4326' }

...

f_set = f.query(**QUERY)
```

The `**` syntax causes the key/value pairs of a dictionary to be split into separate keyword parameters to a function call.  Note that the syntax of a dictionary is somewhat different - the key name has to be quoted, colon instead of equals sign.